# Pythonic dictionary traversal

Tags: django-models, metaprogramming, python

I often find myself in situations where I need to traverse and parse a semi-complex JSON structure. During the traversal, there are certain dictionary `keys` that are expected, and their `values` need to be appropriately mapped to some object (`foo.__dict__`).

Any remaining key/values that did not explicitly map to an object (`foo.additional_attributes(**remaining)`) will need to be isolated and so can be handled as miscellaneous key/value attributes.

Is there some combination of build-in functions simplifying this kind of traversal, mapping, and isolation, making it more dynamic and Pythonic?

Comment: a test case (with input and output) would be most helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pop` method of dictionaries:

```
for key in expected_keys:
    foo.__dict__[key] = d.pop(key)
foo.additional_attributes(**d)
```